# Is the project "cleaned" on the users device when he/she downloads an update from the app store?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, app-store, migration

I use Core Data. During development when I add a new model version, I need to clean my project in xcode before I build it, so that a migration to the new model version takes place.

So when my users update their app is their app "cleaned" as well before the first start?
Or do I need to force migration in another way?

To be more precise: When I just build my new app version (with a new core data model version) in xcode and run it on the device it crashes whenever I try to access new properties of my managed objects (since it did not migrate the sqlite DB to the new model).

Comment: The NSUserdefaults will be saved and maybe also core data pieces. But at the end its an overwrite of the app. All will be deleted

Comment: There are tons of questions about Core Data versioning on SO, and also a complete guide by Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the way you understand "cleaned", the apps of your users are put into an executable state. All data stored in Core Data's persistent store will be migrated to the new store and will be available as before.

In fact, that is the whole point of Apple's migration scheme. As pointed out by FR, read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html).

Comment: For me the doc suggested that migration takes place automatically and anytime I call  addPersistentStoreWithType: . However, I could not find the part where it says "as a dev you have to clean your project before migration". So I was a bit irritated that maybe this error only occurs for me. (<- argh, sorry for my english)